# Non-constant expression in Pyomo

Tags: linear-programming, finance, pyomo

I need to include a calculation in Pyomo optimization but I receive a message that it becomes boolean logic. I am using glpk which is suitable for linear programming. Is there an alternative to include this calculation in the optimization? Below is a very simplified example.

```
spread_min_150  =  0.01
spread_150_max  =  0.05

SPOT = 600
avg = 10


def price(SPOT, POSITION, spread_min_150, spread_150_max):
    if SPOT < 150:
        spread_price  =  SPOT * (1 + spread_min_150) if POSITION >= 0 else SPOT * (1 - spread_min_150)
    else:
        spread_price  =  SPOT * (1 + spread_150_max) if POSITION >= 0 else SPOT * (1 - spread_150_max)
    return spread_price

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.a = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.b = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

mcp = avg  - (model.a + model.b)

B = mcp * price(SPOT, mcp, spread_min_150, spread_150_max)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=B, sense=pyo.minimize)

model.obj.pprint()

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
result = opt.solve(model)
print(result)
model.display()
```

The error message is below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PyomoException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c4ab9fc5d44c> in <cell line: 21>()
     19 mcp = avg  - (model.a + model.b)
     20 
---> 21 B = mcp * price(SPOT, mcp, spread_min_150, spread_150_max)
     22 
     23 model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=B, sense=pyo.minimize)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyomo/core/expr/relational_expr.py in __bool__(self)
     46         if self.is_constant():
     47             return bool(self())
---> 48         raise PyomoException(
     49             """
     50 Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (%s) to bool.

PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (0  <=  10 - (a + b)) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality. For example,
    >>> m.x = Var()
    >>> if m.x >= 1:
    ...     pass
and
    >>> m.y = Var()
    >>> if m.y in [m.x, m.y]:
    ...     pass
would both cause this exception.
```